# text field text indent

Tags: css, forms

How do I properly indent text in a text field?  I am currently using this for the css, but it doesn't seem to work in IE.

```
text-indent:15px;
```

Basically, I have an image, and would like to indent it about 15 px.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jn4SW/

```
input{
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  margin: 20px;    
}​
```

I Updated the jsfiddle to include a background image:

http://jsfiddle.net/jn4SW/1/

Comment: i've tried padding-left:15px; but it seems to push my background image 15 px to the right.

Comment: isn't that what you want to do?  Your question specifically states you want to indent it 15px.

Comment: i just subtracted 15px from the image to that it does not repeat horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Please add **line-height** in your css it will work also ie6